# Continuation of Comment Line

Tags: assembly, zos

I am parsing some IBM Assembly Language which also happens to be a BMS map.

The code looks like this:

```
*02LN    DFHMDF POS=(04,05),LENGTH=70,ATTRB=(ASKIP,BRT),               X
               HILIGHT=REVERSE,COLOR=BLUE
```

Note that the first line is a comment based on the * in the first column.

Is the second line also a comment because the first line has a continuation character?

The context of this question is that I am parsing the code without a mainframe as I am converting these maps to a different system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the HLASM reference:

> Comment statements must lie within the statement field. If the comment extends into the
>   continuation-indicator field, the statement following the comment statement is considered a
>   continuation line of that comment statement.

So your guess is right: you can also create multiline-comments by using the continuation-indicator.